# How to make a on reaction, add role command in python?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to add a role on reaction to a message, i want the bot to send the message and then react on it, the code below is what i made for sending reacts to it, but only giving roles to the author, i want the role to be given to whoever reacts.

`````
async def react(ctx):

    msg = await ctx.send('Testing')
    await msg.add_reaction('\U00002642')
    guild = bot.get_guild(693430519702224936)
    role = guild.get_role(696799598865547376)
    author = ctx.message.author
    await author.add_roles(role)````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@client.event()
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction == '\U00002642':
        role = guild.get_role(696799598865547376)
        await user.add_roles(role)
```

This is an event. This happens whenever a user reacts with the message. If the following doesn't work, try:

```
@client.event()
async def on_reaction_add(reaction='\U00002642', user):
    role = guild.get_role(696799598865547376)
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: but what if i want to check for reactions on a specific message? moreover im getting permission issue, even if the person using the reaction has a role lower the bot and the bot has admin roles